# Compressing files through command line on a Windows system

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to compress one folder on my local disk, for example: `C:\Templates`

I am using the below command from command line (cmd.exe) to do this operation:

```
compact /c C:\Templates
```

But it is not working, and shows the following message:

```
1 files within 1 directory were compressed.    
0 total bytes of data are stored in 0 bytes.      
The compression ratio is 1.0 to 1.
```

My machine is running Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: One more information, the folder color is changing to blue but the size remains the same on disk.

Comment: Should I put some more information, I really need the solution...

Comment: Do you insist on using 'compact'?You can try other compression utility in command line.

Comment: @Magic: Can you give more detials about the compression utility in command line ?

Comment: http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip

Comment: @Jash,  Take a look at http://www.7-zip.org/ it has a command line utility.7zip is a high compression ratio tool.

Comment: zip/unzip/7zip is not the same. The Windows compact function is transparent - the file system stores it compressed and transparently uncompresses when the file is accessed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
compact /c /s:C:\Templates
```

The only thing you are missing is the `/s` switch before the directory name.

Comment: Thanks, atcullay I even used the /s switch but missed the colon.

Comment: One more thing, when i compress it then i try to copy it some other location with the following command:
copy /y "C:\Files\TemplateFiles" "C:\ABC
But it is giving the error file not found. Does the name or extension of TemplateFiles changes after the compression

Comment: use XCopy, you are probably creating new directory C:\ABC, if it does not exist then copy will fail, Xcopy will create the new directory in case of non existance

Comment: I am using the following command:
xcopy "C:\Files\TemplateFiles" "some server"

Comment: I am using the following command: xcopy "C:\Files\TemplateFiles" "some server"
but it is not working. Also it is deleting the folder present in server. strange.

Comment: I believe its a problem in your target location, try dir  "C:\Files\TemplateFiles" , if it shows directory listing, then the source folder is ok, try the same with target folder

Comment: You might want to add the `/i` switch to ignore any errors in the process and therefore compress anything you can (otherwise, any error will stop the compression operation in the middle of your files).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the directory isn't empty?  It will give that message on empty directories.  Future files put there will be compressed.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, using compact.exe will **not work** if cluster size is larger than 4096 bytes. I formatted a drive with a 8192-byte cluster size, and later found out that NTFS compression doesn't work with it.